# How To Place This Javascript Wildcard in a Function and Make It Stop at a &

Tags: javascript, wildcard

I have this Javascript code

```
function() {
  var link_id = {{Click Path}}.split('/')[2];
  if({{Event}}.match(/hr.*/)) return {{Event}};
  if(link_id.match(/hr.*/)) return link_id;
  return false;
}
```

Which takes my urls that are formatted like this
https://www.example.org/go/hr1234/
and reports the id as an event in GA4 as "hr1234" (without quotes). That all works perfectly.

BUT

I also have urls that look like this.... https://www.example.org/go/uniquename/?param1=something1&gclid=DYNAMICNUMBER&param2=something
and I want to capture the DYNAMICNUMBER after gclid= and stop once it hits a & so I do not get any other parameters following it.

I have tried a bunch of variations of the above with no luck. Here is an example of what I have tried.

```
function() {
  var link_id = {{Click Path}}.split('/')[2];
  if({{Event}}.match(gclid=.*)) return {{Event}};
  if(link_id.match(gclid=.*)) return link_id;
  return false;
}
```

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL  https://nodejs.org/api/url.html

Comment: What is this? This looks like invalid js? `{{Click Path}`, `gclid=.*`, `{{Event}}`.

Comment: I am using it in Google Tag Manager and so the {{Click Path} and {{Event}} work with it. That part works ok....gclid=.* is what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried to modify your code so it works as you wish:

```
function() {
  var link_id = {{Click Path}}.split('/')[2];
  var gclid = {{Click Path}}.match(/gclid=([^&]*)/);
  if (gclid) return gclid[1];
  if ({{Event}}.match(/hr.*/)) return {{Event}};
  if (link_id.match(/hr.*/)) return link_id;
  return false;
}
```

- /gclid=([^&]*)/ matches the text gclid= followed by any number of characters that are not &. The parentheses () capture the matched text, so you can access it using the array returned by the match method
- gclid=.* match everything after gclid= until the end of the string, including any & characters and subsequent parameters. To stop at the first & character, you can use the regular expression gclid=([^&]*) instead
- match() method returns an array of matches, not a single match. use the array index [1]

EDIT:
As asked in the comment, ff you want to get everything after the first `=` you can use `split` :

```js
var url = 'example.org/go/uniquename/?param1=GETTHIS';
var value = url.split('=')[1];
console.log(value); // Outputs: "GETTHIS
```

Comment: I think I can get that to work as desired. What if I wanted to get everything after a = sign all on its own as a st6andalone JS? For example I just want anything after = in a link like this https://www.example.org/go/uniquename/?param1=GETTHIS

Comment: Updated my answer to address your question